# openpyxl iterate through rows and apply formula

Tags: python, excel, iteration, openpyxl

I am trying to iterate through the rows of a particular column in an Excel worksheet, apply a formula, and save the output. I'm struggling to get my code right and am not sure where to go next.

My code so far:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test-in.xlsx')
sheet = wb.worksheets[2]
maxRow = sheet.max_row

for row in range(2, maxRow)



wb.save('test-out.xlsx')
```

So I'm not clear how to write my for loop to write the results of applying the =CLEAN(D2) formula, in column E. I can apply the formula to a single cell with:

```
sheet['I2'] = '=CLEAN(D2)'
```

However I'm not sure how I can incorporate this into my for loop!

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (max_row_num is yours maxRow - in Python we usually do not use cameCase for variables):

```
for row_num in range(2, max_row_num):
    sheet['E{}'.format(row_num)] = '=CLEAN(D{})'.format(row_num)
```

Comment: Thank you that works great, I think I was over complicating this in my head.
Understood about var naming, old habits :)

Comment: This works very nicely, however the output file contains cells with the above formula in them. I don't want to send the sheet with formulas in it, I just want the resulting values. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's strange. Are you opening it with Excel (openpyxl needs data_only=True in  load_workbook to read formula values)?

Comment: Alex, I've posted a new question for this as I though you've already answered my question here and it might be fairer for you to get credit with the new question. It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046676/openpyxl-output-formula-results-not-formula-into-cells
No I'm not using that flag though.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells